# Showing clear relationship in nested html table

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I am working on a nested table where each level except the first level is connected to its parent level with a vertical and horizontal line as shown below.

[image: current issue]

My issue occurs, when the second level appears after the third level. It becomes difficult to link it to the first level, so it currently appears like its hanging.

I have tried putting a border on table-level-one to take the height of the table. That didn't work because in a situation where level three is the last item, there would be a hanging border.

This is the perfect scenario here.
[image: ideal]

I achieved this by increasing the height of the pseudo element to a high number like 96px but there is a border overflow.

```
td.first {
   div {      
    &::after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 2px;
    height: 96px;
    left: -27px;
    background: black;
    top: -33px;
  }
}
```

I have created a demo here on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-d3vj9n?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I am open to html and css changes only.

Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you just try it in reverse way. Try to connect from root level to the first and third level.

Comment: I have actually reversed it and I’ve got an almost perfect solution which I’d be posting soon. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By targeting the last level-two row we can override the vertical bar and given it a huge height value as shown below.

```
.level-two {
    &:last-child {
        td.first {
            div.inner {
                &::after {
                    height: 200px;
                    top: -185px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The vertical line would likely sit on top row above and this can be fixed using z-index and overflow hidden. Here is a link to [demo](https://angular-table-fix-2.stackblitz.io/)